# Build a sequence of functions

Tags: probability-theory

Build a sequence of functions $(f_n(x))_{n\ge 0}, 0 \le f_n \le 1$, such that $\int f_n d\mu \rightarrow 0$, but for any $x \in R, (f_n(x))_{n\ge 0}$ it does not converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On $[0,1]$, do the following.   Let $f_0 = 1$.  Then let $f_1$, $f_2$ and $f_3$ be the indicator functions of $[0,1/3]$ and $[1/3, 2/3]$ and $[2/3, 1]$.  Now march across in in fourths, fifths, etc.  These will converge nowhere, but their integrals converge to 0 since they are supported on smaller and smaller intervals.

Comment: And this could presumably be extended to all of $\mathbb{R}$ by marching across from -1 to 1 in thirds, then from -2 to 2 in quarters, etc. etc.

Comment: You could widen the interval each time.  but you have to be careful about integers (you don't want convergence there), so widen by some exotic factor like $\pi$. Since $\pi$ is not algebraic, this should keep you out of trouble.

Comment: I meant: march from -2 to +2 in steps of 0.25 etc. That would surely avoid any possible problems at integers.